# Why can we ignore the absolute value while solving the following differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

*Right after substituting $y=vx$, Is it because we assume $x>0$?

$y\,dy + x\,dx = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dx$
$\implies y\,dy = (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - x)\,dx$
$\implies \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - x}{y}$
$\implies \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (v x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + v^2 x^2} - x}{v x}$

substituting $y = v x$ gives

$$\implies v + x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1+ v^2} - 1}{v}
\implies x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} =  \dfrac{\sqrt{1+ v^2} - 1}{v} - v$$
$$\implies x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1+ v^2} - 1 - v^2}{v} 
\implies \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} - 1 - v^2} \,dv= \dfrac{dx}{x}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})}\,dv = \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Let $A =\displaystyle\int  \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})}\,dv $
and $1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2} = t$
$$\implies -\dfrac{1}{2} (1 + v^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (2 v) dv = dt
 \implies -\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}\,dv = dt$$
$$\implies A = -\displaystyle\int \dfrac{dt}{t} = -\ln t = - \ln (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})$$
$$\implies\displaystyle\int  \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})}\,dv  =  - \ln (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})$$
$$\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} - 1 - v^2} \,dv= \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Integrating both sides

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} - 1 - v^2} \,dv = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{dx}{x}
\implies -\ln (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2}) = \ln x + \ln c$$
$$\implies (1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2})^{-1} =  c x
\implies  1 - \sqrt{1 + v^2} = \dfrac{1}{ c x}
\implies 1 - \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{y^2}{x^2}} = \dfrac{1}{c x}$$
$$\implies 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x} = \dfrac{1}{c x}
\implies \dfrac{x - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x} = \dfrac{1}{c x}$$
$$\implies x - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \dfrac{1}{c} = C
\implies -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  = C - x
\implies x^2 + y^2 = (C - x)^2 = C^2 + x^2 - 2 C x
\implies y^2 = C^2 - 2 C x
\implies y^2 + 2 C x - C^2 = 0$$

Comment: No $x$ is not necessary $>0$. When you substitute $y=vx$ you assume nothing on the variable $x$.

Comment: But we get rid of the absolute value. Why?

Comment: The substitution of $y=vx$ has nothing to do with the absolute value since inside the root you have $v^2+1$ which is always positive.

Comment: @Aryadeva It's in the next step: In general, $\sqrt{x^2 + v^2 x^2}$ is $|x| \sqrt{1 + v^2}$, not $x \sqrt{1+v^2}$. **That's** the absolute value.

Comment: Nothing to do with the substitution. You can do that without any substitution you know ....

Comment: You should have an absolute value yes. But this is not related to the substitution. Just answered your question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$y\,dy + x\,dx = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dx$$
Is simply:
$$\dfrac {d(x^2+y^2) }{ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}=2dx$$
$$\int \dfrac {du }{ \sqrt{u}}=x^2+c_1$$
$$ \sqrt{u}=\dfrac 12x^2+C$$
And $u=x^2+y^2 >0$.
$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac 12x^2+C$$

Comment: I know. I would like an answer about my question please. Thank you.

Comment: well $u >0$ it's always positive. @user25275

Comment: I want an explanation related to the answer in the details please.